# HTTPS on Google Cloud Container Engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I have some containers running on Google Cloud Container Engine which work fine over http, but I am wondering about what the ideal setup would be for enable https/ssl termination for those services.

Is it possible to do this in GCCE directly (or via kubernetes) or should I setup a nginx vm and internally link to the containers (this would probably give issues with the dynamic IP's assigned to the containers).

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access your containers externally then Google has an [HTTPS L7 load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#https_load_balancing). You want to configure a Ingress with SSL suport.

There are also some [community contributed examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/561#issuecomment-102123959) of using nginx to load balance requests across containers that could probably be easily modified to support SSL termination.

Comment: Ok, how about accessing DNS info on the pod names from one of our other cloud vm's? Is there a way to manage that? I can't see how I can get the ip adres from within the project (we currently have an NGINX forwarder which we use for parts outside the container engine)...

Comment: I've found the kube-dns server and see that the internal kubernetes.local hostname gives results, but I can't find the actual pod records. I see that *.default.kubernetes.local gives me the results, but the results I get are not the internal IP addresses of the containers. Am I using the wrong FQDN?

Comment: The DNS names that kube2sky grabs are for the cluster services (not the pods). If you want to configure nginx to know about pods (rather than services) you should be able to write a simple program that watches the endpoints and writes out the nginx config as pods come and go. From the example I linked above, the https://github.com/just-containers/loadbalancer-feeder looks to do exactly this -- so you can either try to use that as is or repurpose the code to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe I'm a noob at this, but I can't seem to figure out how I should set it up...

Comment: If you are having trouble setting up loadbalancer-feeder I'd suggest asking the author by opening an issue on the github page.